# PHP can't download files from another server locally when accessed with browser

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to download a file locally from a remote server but every time i access the file that contains the PHP code using the browser `file_get_contents()` fails because it doesn't have the permission to write to `/var/www/html` (Apache2). I tried using cURL but that didn't work either, checked to see if `allow_url_fopen` is on (it is) and added the php file to `sudoers`. I can't seem to find any solution online.

Comment: does file_GET_contents() fail, of file_PUT_contents()?

Comment: @IvoP file_put_contents(), it returns false;

Comment: So the user under which apache/php is running has no rights to write files on the location you want it to.

Comment: the same as it would be to write any file (upload from user, created logfiles,created images). see chmod and chgrp to give php rights. But what kind of files are you downloading this way?

Comment: @IvoP well i'd like to be able to download any file but for this particular case i'm downloading video files...ill try to give php permission to write and read files (i should also check if im able to create/read files) because i already made sure the apache user has those rights

Answer (score 0):

i think this is permission issue, [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website) maybe will solve your problem, pick that suit to your enviroment.